# Dart: Handle browsers that can't access the FileSystem

Tags: dart

My aim is to try to get access to the browser sandboxed filesystem on chrome and if the user is using another browser to fall back to some other code. I tried the following:

```
print("Attempt to access filesystem");
window.requestFileSystem(1024 * 1024, persistent: false)
    ..then((FileSystem) => print("successfully accessed FileSystem"),onError:(e)
    {
        print("failed to access FileSystem");
    });
```

Testing this in firefox vs. chrome my problem is the error handler does not seem to get reached in firefox (the only thing printed is "Attempt to access filesystem"). I wonder if the problem is that firefox does not handle the .then() syntax. If that is the case, can someone advise how I check that Futures are supported by the browser. And in general can anyone advise how I can achieve this?

Comment: When I run it in Chrome [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/580f89ede28d93b762ae1f44acd05ba7) I get this console output `Attempt to access filesystem` `failed to access FileSystem`

Comment: Yes, that is the expected output. If you try to run it in firefox now - you should get just "Attempt to access filesystem" so it fails to reach the error handler. I was wondering how to get firefox (or other browsers) to reach the error handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to handler errors using `async`/`await`

```
import 'dart:html';
main() async {
  try {
    print("Attempt to access filesystem");
    var fileSystem = await window.requestFileSystem(1024 * 1024, persistent: false);
    print("successfully accessed FileSystem");
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
    print("failed to access FileSystem");
  }
}
```

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/a1e6ba093d569376e43785fcc072a659)

With your code `try`/`catch` also works (in addition to `onError` because the error happens in the sync code (method `window.requestFileSystem` doesn't exist (in Safari)

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/9bb988bda18a2f48dbdafee840c9398d)

Comment: Ah I see - that is great. Thanks!